# Python: Reading n lines at a time in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, slice

I'm new to python so I know there has to be a more elegant way to do this and was hoping to get some advice on this.

Currently, I have a list that consists of x entries. I want to:

- Read n entries from the list at a time
- Do a computation with those n entries (calculating a standard deviation, so for that I need to get the mean of the n entries)
- Move on to the next n entries, and do another calculation with this new set of data
- Append all these values into a file

Right now, I'm going very primitive and just doing something like:

```
first = mylist[0:11]
mean = sum(first)/nentries
second = mylist{11:22]
mean2 = sum(second)/nentries
...
```

As you can see, this is extremely novice and not elegant at all if I have say 352 entries and I need to read 11 lines at a time from them. Is there an easy way to loop over the list and only pick out n entries (in this case, 11) at a time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

why not using `range`:

```
range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers
```

In your case:

```
for start in range(0,len(mylist), 11):
    end = start + 11
    blablabla
```

or `itertools.count`:

```
range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! This is a really novice question (if you can't tell I'm a complete beginner) but after I've set up this for loop that uses the range and goes through 11 elements at a time, how would I do a computation? Wouldn't each set of 11 elements have to be stored somewhere (to be added together and divided by 11 to get the mean)?

Comment: Also, won't this just give me every11th element of my list? In this case, I want the first 11 elements, and then the next 11 elements, and so on.